# Height transitions and pagination counts

Tags: user-expectation, pagination

Say for instance I have a grid that lists users and also gives administrators the ability to add users. Once a user is added the grid grows in height. After 10 users the additional users added are displayed on the screen by using pagination.

My question is should the box retain the height of the 10 users when when displaying the 2nd set of users, even if the total does not amount to 10?

My guts says to have this be an height that relates the the amount of users and not have the huge empty row.

Below is an example.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most cases I would leave the table height the same when navigating to the next page. The main reason is that the controls at the bottom of your page should stay fixed so the user doesn't have to move the mouse to hit the previous button. Another reason is that if there are elements below the table you have to make sure content doesn't jump up and down when you flip pages. You can avoid that with various layout techniques, but it may be better to just have that empty space as part of the table instead of somewhere else.

The only time I would consider adjusting the table height is if it's common to navigate there with the table already showing the last page.

Comment: Agree. You could also try seeing what the controls look like at the top.  This also avoids them jumping around or disappearing if you have an unknown window height. Or even both top and bottom. May be a bit cluttered though.